# Flight from India to Cayman islands non -via USA/UK

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, cayman-islands

I recently found out that if I travel From India to the Cayman Islands via UK/USA, I will need a transit visa. So which countries or route or airway should I choose to get to the Cayman Islands for which a transit visa will not be needed?

Comment: If you look up [flight arrivals](http://www.caymanairports.ky/ContentDisplay.aspx/passenger-information/flightinfo/arrivals/gcm) on the GCM website, you can see what cities are served. You can investigate Canada, the Bahamas, and Cuba.

Answer (score 6):

[Rome2Rio suggests](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Delhi/Cayman-Islands) flying **Delhi-Amsterdam-Havana** on KLM, continuing to Grand Cayman on Cayman Airways.  Assuming you're an Indian passport holder, you should *not* need an [airport transit visa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Airport_transit) for the Netherlands (Schengen), and Cuba [apparently also does not require a visa](http://www.travcour.com/g_page.php?pageid=1121&Pagetitle=Cuba) if you're continuing to a third country within 72 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the best route for Grand cayman from Delhi.

- Delhi (Del) to Moscow (SVO) on Aeroflot. Non-stop.
- Layover. 2.40 Hrs.
- Moscow (Svo) to Havana (Hav) on Aeroflot. Non-stop.
- Layover 23Hrs.
- Havana to Grand Cayman on Cayman Airways.