# How to enforce transit points during flight booking to avoid transit visas?

Tags: air-travel, transit-visas

I am using skyscanner to search for international flights. It is an outstanding app, but when searching for flights from India to Cayman Islands it only shows connections through USA and UK. Why are there no other connections listed (e.g., through Russia) for which I do not require a transit visa?

Comment: From where to where your flight is? Tell us names of the airports

Comment: I already mentioned from India,CCU to Grand Cayman,GCM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flight from India to Cayman islands non -via USA/UK](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/flight-from-india-to-cayman-islands-non-via-usa-uk)

Comment: Also, CCU has only a few direct flights to Europe.  Try searching from DEL or BOM instead, then add in a cheap domestic flight.

Comment: Are you trying to **enforce** transit points or **find** them? Not everywhere is reachable from everywhere else.

Comment: I am satisfied whatever reply you guys have given but i need a little bit more clearly. If you are annoyed then sorry for asking these questions.

Comment: @jpatokal he's new, we can explain the rules kindly, as per the [help]. :)

Comment: Hi Imso. If I were you I would go to a travel agent and tell them what you want, and let them find you a flight. These people are professionals, and if the flight exists, they will find it. Chances are they will save you more money than the fee they charge.

Answer (score 1):

The Cayman Islands aren't a huge international travel destination, and the only big international [airlines which land there](http://www.grand-cayman-gcm.airports-guides.com/gcm_airport_airlines.html) are British, American and Canadian. Since airlines almost always offer only flights from and to the hub airports in their home country (for various reasons, such as taxes and regulations), you won't find any direct flights between the Caymans and countries other than those three (except for Cayman Airways and a Honduran airline, but those are regional).

Comment: Thnx for the answer. But i want to know is there any indirect or multiple flight that go to GCM. The three countries tou named all required transit visa right! I just need the routes or ways that i dont required transit visa . Ready to change any numbers of flight required.

Comment: @Imso1987: according to the airport's website (see link in answer) Cayman Airways provides regular services from Kingston, Jamaica - that might be a possibility.

Comment: Ok. I have also seen somewhere the route as   Kolkata-Dubai-Moscow-Havana-Georgetown.  If i go with these destinations, do i need transit visa for any of these countries???

Comment: @Imso1987: I have no idea. Shouldn't be too hard to find out on the various embassies' websites.

Comment: Ok. Suppose i go with ur option, i.e. To jamaica. But india to jamaica have connecting flight from USA or UK. ? Then here also i need transit visa??

Comment: @lmso1987 I don't think that Cubana allows booking through sites like Skyscanner.

Comment: I just want reviews and opinions abt it. And u all guys are so much outstanding. Nothing to say more.